# In Python how do I read data from stdin until piped process terminates?

Tags: python-3.x, pipe, stdin

I'd like to do something like this:

```
data = json.load(open(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin)
```

which for this example can be reduced to

```
data = json.load(sys.stdin)
```

But `json.load` runs a single `.read()` which might not contain the whole JSON string I provided via

```
generate_json_output | myprogram.py
```

Is there a recommended way to read from `stdin` until `generate_json_output` terminates? I tried to catch `BrokenPipeError` but it doesn't get raised when I run

```
while True:
    data += sys.stdin.read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `while` loop, you can use for loop like below to iterate over stdin.

```
import sys

data = ''
for line in sys.stdin:
    data += line
```

which can be written as one expression:

```
data = "".join(sys.stdin)
```

Running this with input generated using a pipe reads the stdin until it terminates.

t.json:

```
{
    'a': 2,
    'b': 3
}
```

Running `cat t.json | python a.py` prints the complete file to stdout.

Comment: This is as straight forward as I was hoping it would be :)  shorter version: `data = "".join(sys.stdin)`